# AMcharts XY chart custom zoom-in button

Tags: zooming, amcharts

I've been searching for a way to zoom my XY chart to desired coordinates without having user to select chart area. I know XY chart has `zoomOut()` function but is there a way to zoom in too? Would like to add a zoom-in button with my chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use valueAxis [zoomToValues](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#zoomToValues) to zoom based on the values.

```
chart.addListener("rendered", function (e) {

  var valueAxes = e.chart.valueAxes;

  valueAxes[0].zoomToValues(-8, 15);
  valueAxes[1].zoomToValues(-8, 8);
});
```

Please see [this example](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/71f3d4908f4b9dc08dae8b90c9baab1e)

Comment: Thanx a ton.. I've been trying zoomToIndexes.. .zoomToValues  works!